How to assign Reader role to user in Azure Subscription using Python SDK?
I’m trying to assign "Reader" role to user under Azure subscription using Azure Python SDK. I’ve found a way to do it using Azure REST API following MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest , but I’m not sure how to do the same thing with the SDK.
Here’s the code I’m using with Python’s requests library to call REST API directly:
import requests
import uuid

scope = "subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group_name}"
role_assignment_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
role_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7"  # Reader role ID
principal_id = "{user_principal_id}"

url = f"https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/{role_assignment_id}?api-version=2022-04-01"

access_token = "{access_token}"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

body = {
    "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": role_definition_id,
        "principalId": principal_id
    }
}

response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=body)

if response.status_code == 201:
    print("Role assigned successfully.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to assign role. Status Code: {response.status_code}, Response: {response.text}")

The code above works fine, but I want to switch to using Azure Python SDK instead of directly calling the REST API. I’ve searched through the SDK documentation, but I can’t find any example or method that shows how to assign roles like this.

Could you confirm whether your requirement is to assign Reader role to user using Azure Python SDK under subscription scope?

Yes @Sridevi that's exactly what I need. Please help

Could you confirm whether you want to authenticate using service principal or signed-in user?

obtained bearer token with app owner access, but the user sign-ins aren't applicable to our situation. Is that what you refer to as authentication?

Do you have app id, secret and tenant id values with you? app owner access means app has Owner role assigned under subscription?

Yes, i do have all those values ready with me, can you share me sample code to assign role with them?

Added answer with sample code. Please check and let me know if it works : )

It worked like a charm! Thanks a ton, Sridevi!

Hey @Sridevi! if you’ve got a moment, could you help me out with getting users or applications that have reader role under subscription using Python SDK? I keep encountering errors related to unsupported queries when I try to apply filters. Thank you!

Hi @JamesWilton please post a new question with more details on this requirement by including code, errors and share link here

done @Sridevi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79277696/get-all-users-and-applications-with-reader-role-under-subscription-in-azure-pyth please help me out

Hi @JamesWilton I added answer for your new question. Please check and let me know if it works : )

I have one app registration having Owner access under subscription like this:

To assign "Reader" role to user under Azure subscription using Azure Python SDK with service principal authentication, make use of below sample code:
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.authorization import AuthorizationManagementClient
import uuid

tenant_id = "tenantId"
client_id = "appId"
client_secret = "secret"

subscription_id = "subId"
scope = "subscriptions/subId"
role_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7"
principal_id = "userId"

role_assignment_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

authorization_client = AuthorizationManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

try:
    role_assignment = authorization_client.role_assignments.create(
        scope=scope,
        role_assignment_name=role_assignment_id,
        parameters={
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": role_definition_id,
                "principalId": principal_id
            }
        }
    )
    print("Role assigned successfully:", role_assignment)
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to assign role:", str(e))

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where Reader role assigned successfully to user under subscription as below:


Try this:
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

from azure.mgmt.authorization import AuthorizationManagementClient

import uuid

subscription_id = "{subscription_id}"

resource_group_name = "{resource_group_name}"

principal_id = "{user_principal_id}"  # User's object ID in Azure AD

role_definition_id = "/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7"  

scope = f"/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group_name}"

role_assignment_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

auth_client = AuthorizationManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

try:
    role_assignment = auth_client.role_assignments.create(
        scope=scope,
        role_assignment_name=role_assignment_id,
        parameters={
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": role_definition_id,
                "principalId": principal_id
            }
        }
    )
    print("Role assigned successfully:", role_assignment)
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to assign role:", str(e))


DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot this issue.
ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable.SharedTokenCacheCredential: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.AzureCliCredential: Please run 'az login' to set up an account

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Set the following environment variables with appropriate values for your Azure service principal:
set AZURE_CLIENT_ID=your-client-id
set AZURE_TENANT_ID=your-tenant-id
set AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=your-client-secret

After setting these variables, DefaultAzureCredential will use them to authenticate.

No worries, code from Sridevi is working well at the moment!
