Get all users and applications with Reader role under subscription in Azure Python SDK
I need to fetch users and applications assigned the "Reader" role under a specific Azure subscription using the Azure Python SDK. The AuthorizationManagementClient is being used along with the role_assignments.list_for_scope() method to list role assignments, but an issue arises with the filter query.
Here’s the code that’s being used:
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.authorization import AuthorizationManagementClient

scope = f"subscriptions/{subscription_id}"
reader_role_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)
authorization_client = AuthorizationManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

try:
    print("\nFetching users and applications with 'Reader' role in the subscription...")
    role_assignments = authorization_client.role_assignments.list_for_scope(
        scope=scope,
        filter=f"atScope() and roleDefinitionId eq '{reader_role_definition_id}'"
    )

    print("Users or applications with Reader Role:")
    for assignment in role_assignments:
        print(f"Principal ID: {assignment.principal_id}")
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to fetch users or applications with 'Reader' role:", str(e))

However, upon executing the code, I receive following error message:
Fetching users and applications with 'Reader' role in the subscription...
Users or applications with Reader Role:
Failed to fetch users or applications with 'Reader' role: (UnsupportedQuery) The filter 'atScope() and roleDefinitionId eq '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7'' is not supported. Supported filters are either 'atScope()' or 'principalId eq '{value}' or assignedTo('{value}')'.
Code: UnsupportedQuery
Message: The filter 'atScope() and roleDefinitionId eq '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7'' is not supported. Supported filters are either 'atScope()' or 'principalId eq '{value}' or assignedTo('{value}')'.


Could you confirm whether your requirement is to fetch all these role assignments of Reader role under subscription in Azure Python SDK? https://i.imgur.com/qfpAT4S.png

below code worked @Sridevi but I'm trying to figure out how to tell if the principal ID is for a user or an application. Can you help me tweak the code to make that distinction clearer?

Sure James, will check and update the answer with modified code shortly

You can add "principal_type": role.principal_type in appended results of role. Please check below updated answer and let me know if it works.

I really appreciate your help, Sridevi! That did the trick. You're truly amazing!

Glad to be of help : )

The error occurred as filtering on roleDefinitionId property is not supported. The supported values of $filter query parameter are atScope() or principalId eq '{value}' or assignedTo('{value}')
I have below users and applications with Reader role assigned under subscription:

To fetch these details using Azure Python SDK, you can make use of below sample code:
from azure.mgmt.authorization import AuthorizationManagementClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

tenant_id = "tenantId"
client_id = "appId"
client_secret = "secret"
subscription_id = "subId"

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
authorization_client = AuthorizationManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

def list_readers(client):
    results = []
    subscription_scope = f'/subscriptions/{subscription_id}'
    reader_role_id = 'acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7'
    roles = client.role_assignments.list_for_scope(scope=subscription_scope, filter='atScope()')
    for role in roles:
        if reader_role_id in role.role_definition_id:
            results.append({
                "principal_id": role.principal_id,
                "principal_type": role.principal_type
            })
    return results

try:
    readers = list_readers(authorization_client)
    for reader in readers:
        print(f"Principal ID: {reader['principal_id']}, Principal Type: {reader['principal_type']}")
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to fetch users or applications with 'Reader' role:", str(e))

Response:

